# Ruby on Rails link_to explanation for a n00b?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

1. I'm doing a Rails blog tutorial and don't fully understand the following link_to code

   ```
   <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
   ```

   Why do I have to use:

   ```
   [comment.post, comment]
   ```

   and why can't I just write:

   ```
   @post.comment
   ```
2. My second, related, question is that since I created the "destroy" action in the controller as follows:

   ```
   def destroy
     @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
     @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
     @comment.destroy
     redirect_to post_path(@post)
   ```

   end

   Why don't I have to mention "destroy" in the link_to code?

   ```
   <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],
      method: :delete,
      data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you have to supply both the Post object and the Comment to the link_to helper is because Comment is a nested resource in Post, and both IDs must be known in order to construct the URL. It's actually equivalent to:

`link_to 'Destroy Comment', post_comment_path(comment.post, comment), ...`

What it's doing is it's resolving the path helper for you, using `url_for`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects .

You don't have to mention destroy in your `link_to` because destroy is the name of the action. Your routes file outlines which controllers and actions are associated with which routes.

I assume that you're using resourceful routing, which is shorthand way of defining routes for all of the CRUD actions. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions for the mapping between HTTP verb and controller action. You'll see that `delete` is mapped to `destroy`, and you're using `method: :delete` on your `link_to`.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a lot of things going on here.

1) My guess is that the `link_to` in the first part is within a loop. Is that true? That would be something like `@post.comments.each do |comment|`. If that's the case, then likely what's happening is you have comments nested under posts. That documentation can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). The brackets are to identify the comment, which you need a `post` id for. You could probably also do `[@post, comment]`, which would work just as well. You can't just write `@post.comment` because it's not enough information to identify the correct comment.

2) Rails takes HTTP verbs to identify which action to call from the controller. You're sending an HTTP DELETE request to `/posts/:post_id/comments/:id`, which the routes file then figures out belongs to the comments controller. That documentation can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) and [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).